# How do I change the Alt + Tab task switcher window to show more applications?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I run many apps concurrently and use Alt + Tab constantly.  In fact, I prefer Alt + Tab to having multiple monitors.  I mean, come on, you can only look at one thing at a time and this way I don't have to turn my head :-)

I recently installed Windows 7 and on my previous machine I had modified the Task Switcher window to show more icons without scrolling, but I cannot remember how.  Do you?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Changing the number of icons show in the task-switcher involves editing a couple of registry entries.  They are:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\CoolSwitchColumns
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\CoolSwitchRows
```

Windows XP users can also use the [Microsoft TweakUI Power Toy](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/downloads/powertoys/xppowertoys.mspx) to make this change.
This informations was found on [this site](http://malektips.com/xp-alt-tab-change-layout-rows-columns.html).

Comment: Thank you!  As I come across these little tips and tweaks I'm trying to get them into superuser so they will be easier to find.

Comment: Windows XP users can also use TaskswitchXP (like TrayIt, TaskswitchXP allows to minimize everything to the system tray), a real pity it doesn't work with 7 :( http://www.ntwind.com/software/taskswitchxp.html

Comment: Funny, I just moved to a new machine at work and wanted to do this, having forgotten I posted it here  :-)  Unfortunately this is working for me on Windows 7.  I changed the entries but the UI is not respecting the setting :-(

Comment: Same as @JimClark over here. This answer seems not to be correct for Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative to Windows own task switcher could be [TorkilsTaskSwitcher.](http://www.oelgaard.dk/software/torkilstaskswitcher/)

> TorkilsTaskSwitcher is a utility, which provides an alternative, replacement or supplement to Windows' Alt-Tab invoked task switcher. Particularly for keyboard enthusiasts.

Answer (score 0):

Try [VistaSwitcher](http://www.ntwind.com/software/vistaswitcher.html). It's free and highly configurable alt-tab task switch replacement. It works on XP, Vista and Win7.

Screenshot:
[image: VistaSwitcher Screenshot]

[More screenshots](http://www.ntwind.com/software/vistaswitcher/screenshots.html).

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @heavyd **did not work** for me in Windows 7 SP1 Ultimate for the thumbnails Aero mode.

But I have solved the Columns/Rows matter by using [Alt+Tab Tuner](http://winaero.com/comment.php?comment.news.5) (freeware and portable, no installation required). Worked like a charm.