# Make Windows 10 Alt+Tab show all windows at once instead of paginating

Tags: windows, windows-10, window-manager, alt-tab

When I use Alt+Tab, the preview interface only shows 22 windows, not all windows. How do I make it show all windows on screen at the same time when I Alt+Tab?

If I hold Alt and Tab multiple times, past the last displayed window, then it starts to "scroll" down and reveal the hidden windows.

Windows 10 22H2

Note that this is ***not*** a duplicate of [How do I change the Alt + Tab task switcher window to show more applications?](https://superuser.com/questions/31344/how-do-i-change-the-alt-tab-task-switcher-window-to-show-more-applications) That question specifically asks about Windows 7, and all the answers are dated and do not apply to/work for Windows 10. This other question [Make Alt + Tab Task Switcher show more tasks at once [Windows 10]](https://superuser.com/questions/1772464/make-alt-tab-task-switcher-show-more-tasks-at-once-windows-10) is similar but was wrongly closed as duplicate of the previous question.

Comment: Is using Task View an accepted solution?

Answer (score 1):

## Method 1

You can press <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> to accomplish something similar to <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>. This will open the Task View interface which presents a thumbnail view of presently open windows. This option does require using the mouse to make a selection.

If you absolutely need it to be <kbd>ALT</kbd> instead of <kbd>WIN</kbd> then you could always use [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) to [remap the keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/misc/Remap.htm), however there have been reported issues with remapping these keys.

## Method 2

- Open Settings <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>
- Click/tap on **System** on the left side, and click/tap on **Mulitasking** on the right side. (see screenshot below)
  [image]
- Click/tap on Desktops on the right side to expand it open. (see screenshot below)
- Select On all desktops or Only on the desktop I'm using (default) for what you want in the **Show all the open windows when I press** <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> drop menu. (see screenshot below)

[image]

- You can now close Settings if you like.
  [Source](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/show-all-open-windows-on-alt-tab-for-current-or-all-desktops-in-windows-11.1060/)
  (I haven't tested this option, so if it does not bring all windows into view, please see method 3 below).

## Method 3

(from [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1772471/598567))

To change the number of rows and columns for the Classic Alt+Tab Dialog:

- [Enable the classic Alt+Tab dialog](https://winaero.com/how-to-get-the-old-alt-tab-dialog-in-windows-10/) if needed
- Open the Registry Editor app (`regedit`)
- Go to the following Registry key:
  `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop`
- On the right, modify or create a new STRING (REG_SZ) value
  named `CoolSwitchRows`. This will define the number of rows for
  the classic dialog. The default is 3, and the value range is from 1 to 20.
- Under the same key, modify or create a new STRING (REG_SZ) value named
  `CoolSwitchColumns`. This will define the number of columns for classic dialog. The default is 7, and the value range is from 1 to 43.
- To enable these changes you need to sign out and sign back in to your
  account.

Source :
[Change Number of Rows and Columns for Classic Alt+Tab Dialog](https://winaero.com/change-number-of-rows-and-columns-for-classic-alttab-dialog/).

Answer (score 0):

Windows is only allowing 20 open apps in the `ALT+TAB` in Windows 11 so I doubt you can expect any better in Windows 10.

source: https://www.wepc.com/news/microsoft-is-about-to-limit-alt-tab-functionality-in-windows-11/

Comment: I can’t find any evidence the change in that article actually happened. Furthermore, the author of the question, is running Windows 10 not an Insider Preview build of Windows 11.

Answer (score 0):

Task View will display all the windows on all desktops, in a format
which might be more readable.

The shortcut to open the Task View is <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

You may also assure that the Task View button is shown on the taskbar
by right-click on the taskbar and select "Show Task View button".